# png not scalable LaTeX using TexShop on Mac

Tags: graphics, pdftex, png

After searching for a long time unfortunately I couldn't find a proper answer or used everything I found without any change.

I have several PNG files to include into my thesis but after including a `.png` image it's not possible to scale it or get it in the right position.

Just a short excerpt from my TeX document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\begin{document}
    \section{Motivation}
    \label{sec:motivation}
    Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie.
    Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500,
    als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese
    durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen.

    %
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chapter/intro/images/image.png}
       \caption{caption}
       \label{fig:label}
    \end{figure}
    %

    Lorem Ipsum ist ein einfacher Demo-Text für die Print- und Schriftindustrie.
    Lorem Ipsum ist in der Industrie bereits der Standard Demo-Text seit 1500,
    als ein unbekannter Schriftsteller eine Hand voll Wörter nahm und diese
    durcheinander warf um ein Musterbuch zu erstellen.
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:
[Link to screenshot with png floating out of document](http://cl.ly/image/0X3x1e173P0S)

The image is neither scaled nor on the chosen position.

The LaTeX template above is provided by my university and recommended to use for my thesis. Before using that template I created clean, new document to play around and learn how to use latex.
There I used `.png` images as well with no problems, I could center it, place it in position and scale it.

This document looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}

\begin{document}
    %
    \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[scale=.3]{image.png}
       \caption{caption}
       \label{fig:label}
    \end{figure}
    %
\end{document}
```

Now I'll just go on writing and hope to get any help in here because I don't know what to do anymore except creating a totally new document.

Comment: At first remove the (conflicting) options "dvips" and "pdftex". Delete also the epsfig package. If the problem persist you will have to put the image on the net for inspection.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks and signature, simply upvote any good answers you get. Your user badge will always be shown in your Q and A.

Comment: Many thanks @UlrikeFischer that works!!! Maybe you'd like to answer the question so I can give you a good reputation and mark the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first remove the (conflicting) options `dvips` and `pdftex`. Remove also the `epsfig` package. If the problem persist you will have to put the image on the net for inspection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on ubuntu in Kile, so probably this problem exists in all texlive compilers. For me, alone removing all `dvips` options solved the problem. It is not necessary to remove the `epsfig` package.